# Linear first-order equation1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

Solve the following first-order equation

> $(1+e^x)y'+e^xy=0$

Please help me to solve this question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation is: $$[(1+e^x) y]'=0 $$

Can you go on?

Comment: Thank you, but I can not. :(

Comment: Integrate both sides, and solve for $y$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $z=(e ^x+1)y$, then $z'=$...